# SQL Conditional String compare in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, where-clause

Using SQL Server, I have a stored procedure which I want to make a string search optional.

`@search` is a parameter. If `@search` has a value I want to search for the string, otherwise if it is empty it should bypass the search.

I just wanted to know your thoughts on the optimal way to write an optional string search in a WHERE.

Right now I have it as

```
AND (@search = '' OR [t4].number like '%'+@search+'%')
```

But what I haven't been able to find out is if the like evaluates even if `@search = ''` is true

If it does still compare both sides of the OR then I was thinking of using this

```
AND (CASE WHEN @search = '' THEN 1 
          ELSE (CASE WHEN [t4].number like '%'+@search+'%' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 END) END) = 1
```

Edit:I did a couple tests and it looks like the case does less reads.

Comment: in general, it's not safe to use short circuit (as in your first expression) as optimizer is free to evaluate in any order - see [http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it would work with `LIKE` but my current favorite way to express that is to say:

```
select * from 
  mytable
 where myfield = COALESCE(@optionalValue, myfield)
```

And if `@optionalValue` is null then this evaluates to `myfield = myfield` otherwise `myfield` is checked against `@optionalValue`.

**Edit:** as it turns out, you can say:

```
select * from 
  mytable
 where myfield like ('%' + COALESCE(@optionalValue, myfield) + '%' )
```

And it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Do you lose any performance because your comparing a field to itself? Wouldnt that cause sql to need to read the field even though its not using it?

Comment: The field (err, the column data) for the table is going to have to be read in any case.  Put it in an index and at least the entire row doesn't have to be processed.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions are generally evaluated from left to right, but there's no guarantee that will always be the case. You can help control the order with parenthesis, but the execution plan will depend on a lot of other factors.

However, comparing a `varchar` field against `'%%'` with `LIKE` will match everything anyway.

Comment: I wanted to get the sql reads down to as few to as possible to improve performance, which is why I thought it would work faster if I could prevent the `LIKE` read.

Comment: you can consider adding Non clustered index on the column which is not going to scan the complete table due to it's index advantage at the bottom of the page which contains address of all records http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/index-data-structures/

Answer (score 1):

> But what I haven't been able to find out is if the like checks even if
>   @search = '' is true

**Check the sample below this will by pass the search in case it is empty otherwise it will perform search...**

```
  create table #temp
    (
        dat smalldatetime,
        Solution_ID int,
        stri varchar(100)
    )

insert into #temp(dat, Solution_ID, stri)values(GETDATE(), 1,  '')
insert into #temp(dat, Solution_ID, stri)values(GETDATE()+1, 2,  'ed')
insert into #temp(dat, Solution_ID, stri)values(GETDATE()+2, 3, 'edede')

select * from #temp
where myfield like '%' + coalesce(@searchString, myfield) + '%'
drop table #temp
```

[image]

you can consider adding Non clustered index on the column which is not going to scan the complete table due to it's index advantage at the bottom of the page which contains address of all records [Non ClusteredIndex => Refernce](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/index-data-structures/)

Comment: Thats a good example, but Im not sure what you are trying to say. I meant to ask if the like evaluates when the first statement in OR is true.

Answer (score 1):

You are (mostly) safe to assume short circuit evaluation in a `CASE` statement, but not in statements of your first type.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2011/03/03/don-t-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case.aspx) shows you at least one edge case where even `CASE` short circuiting fails.